# Access environment variable value in dot reference operator in Python

Tags: python

I have a MongoDB database with the following details:

Database name : `myFirstDB` also stored in environment variable `DB_NAME`
Collection name : `myFirstCollection` also stored in environment variable `DB_COLLEC`

I have the following python code:

`db = get_db()` where get_db() returns the pyMongo client connection.

I want to create a collections object like this:
`users = db.(os.environ.get('DB_NAME')).(os.environ.get('DB_COLLEC'))`

But this always returns syntax error.

What's the alternative way to use env variables with reference operators?

**Edit: Updating for more details.**

```
def get_db():
    if 'db' not in g:
        g.db = MongoClient(os.environ.get('DB_URI'), ssl_cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_NONE)
    return g.db
```

```
def register():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        db = get_db()

        ### Below Line ###
        users = db.myFirstDBname.myFirstCollection 
        ### Above Line ###

        error = None
        if not username:
            error = 'Username is required.'
        elif not password:
            error = 'Password is required.'
        existing_user = users.find_one({'name' : request.form['username']})
       // rest of the code
.
.
.
```

I want to use environment variables in the line above. The same line is repeated in other functions. If I want to change the DB name or Collection, I have to hard code changes in multiple places. Hence the env variables attempt.

Comment: please also try to print the values after reading from env variables...and if u don't mentioned can also put what is the error you're getting

Answer (score 0):

I would make my code like below.

```
import os
import pymongo


def get_db():
    return pymongo.MongoClient(os.getenv('DB_URI'))

def get_collection(db_name, coll_name):
    db_connect = get_db()
    return db_connect[db_name][coll_name]

def register():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']

        ### Below Line ###
        users = get_collection(os.getenv('DB_NAME'), os.getenv('DB_COLLEC'))
        ### Above Line ###

        error = None
        if not username:
            error = 'Username is required.'
        elif not password:
            error = 'Password is required.'
        existing_user = users.find_one({'name' : request.form['username']})
       // rest of the code
.
.
.
```

Comment: ok..where do have your environment variables and what is the error

Comment: It's kind of obscure. I get "TypeError: name must be an instance of str". Will update the question with more info.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the builtin function [`getattr(object, name[, default])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr). It returns the attribute `name` of the object `object`, and, if you pass it an optional `default` value, returns that instead of raising an `AttributeError` in case `object` doesn't have an attribute `name`. The line you marked could be like this:

```py
users = getattr(getattr(db, os.environ.get('DB_NAME')), os.environ.get('DB_COLLEC')))
```

Or as a multiliner:

```py
db_name = getattr(db, os.environ.get('DB_NAME'))
collect_name = getattr(db_name, os.environ.get('DB_COLLEC'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
users = db.myFirstDBname.myFirstCollection
```

try:

```
users = db[myFirstDBname].myFirstCollection
```